# Find the keyboard x-y coordinates

Tags: android, keyboard

I need to find the x-y coordinates for each key that have been pressed
How can I interact with the keyboard? 
I already tried  OnKeyListener with the onKey() method without luck..

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            String key = String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode());
            int[] location = new int[2];
            v.getLocationInWindow(location);
            int x = location[0] + v.getWidth() / 2;
            int y = location[1] + v.getHeight() / 2;
            KeyVals keyVals = new KeyVals(x,key,y);
            keyVal.add(keyVals);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think its not possible and also if u put some complex logic's to find that and figure x and y also, it would be different on different devices..

Comment: I think DJphy is right. What is it you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to explore some things with this data and I need the x-y values for each key press

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution for this was to create my own keyboard and then I could track the x-y coordinates